# Who sang this? It wasn't Carol

Tags: word, knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, word-property, music

I There I Underneath I More Make All

I There And Underneath

I There Santa With I More Make All

I I And Underneath

I To I To

etc.

**Question**

Can you remind me who had a hit with this song? It's about time to listen to it again.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The singer was:

> **Mariah Carey** - the song is her 1994 festive hit, *[All I Want For Christmas Is You](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_I_Want_for_Christmas_Is_You)*.

You can work this out by noticing that the words listed here are:

> the **first words of each line of the song**:
>
>  ***I** don't want a lot for Christmas
>
>  **There** is just one thing I need
>
>  **I** don't care about the presents
>
>  **Underneath** the Christmas tree
>
>  **I** just want you for my own
>
>  **More** than you could ever know
>
>  **Make** my wish come true
>
>  **All** I want for Christmas is you, yeah
>
>
>
>  **I** don't want a lot for Christmas
>
>  **There** is just one thing I need
>
>  **And** I don't care about the presents
>
>  **Underneath** the Christmas tree
>
>
>
>  **I** don't need to hang my stocking
>
>  **There** upon the fireplace
>
>  **Santa** Claus won't make me happy
>
>  **With** a toy on Christmas Day
>
>  **I** just want you for my own
>
>  **More** than you could ever know
>
>  **Make** my wish come true
>
>  **All** I want for Christmas is you (You, baby)
>
>
>
>  (Oh,) **I** won't ask for much this Christmas
>
>  **I** won't even wish for snow
>
>  **And** I'm just gonna keep on waiting
>
>  **Underneath** the mistletoe
>
>
>
>  **I** won't make a list and send it
>
>  **To** the North Pole for Saint Nick
>
>  **I** won't even stay awake
>
>  **To** hear those magic reindeer click...*
>
>  etc.

PS When you say "It's about time to listen to it again", I guarantee you I've been hearing this over and over for weeks already!